# Sklearn's RobustScaler doesn't scale certain columns at all

Tags: python, scikit-learn, normalization

I have the following Pandas DF:

```
    A       B
0   0.0     114422.0
1   99997.0     174382.0
2   0.0     24863.0
3   0.0     91559.0
4   0.0     94248.0
5   0.0     66020.0
6   0.0     61543.0
7   0.0     69267.0
8   0.0     6253.0
9   0.0     93002.0
10  0.0     13891.0
11  0.0     49261.0
12  0.0     20050.0
13  0.0     24710.0
14  0.0     10034.0
15  0.0     24508.0
16  0.0     18249.0
17  0.0     50646.0
18  0.0     150033.0
19  0.0     68424.0
20  0.0     125526.0
21  0.0     110526.0
22  40000.0     217450.0
23  0.0     75543.0
24  145000.0    305310.0
25  12000.0     98583.0
26  0.0     262202.0
27  0.0     277680.0
28  0.0     101420.0
29  0.0     109480.0
30  0.0     65230.0
```

which I tried to normalize (columnswise) with scikit-learn's RobustScaler:

```
array_scaled = RobustScaler().fit_transform(df)
df_scaled = pd.DataFrame(array_scaled, columns = df.columns)
```

However, in the resulted `df_scaled` the first column has not been scaled (or changed) at all:

```
    A       B
0   0.0     0.515555
1   99997.0     1.310653
2   0.0     -0.672042
3   0.0     0.212380
4   0.0     0.248037
5   0.0     -0.126280
6   0.0     -0.185647
7   0.0     -0.083223
8   0.0     -0.918819
9   0.0     0.231515
10  0.0     -0.817536
11  0.0     -0.348512
12  0.0     -0.735864
13  0.0     -0.674070
14  0.0     -0.868681
15  0.0     -0.676749
16  0.0     -0.759746
17  0.0     -0.330146
18  0.0     0.987774
19  0.0     -0.094401
20  0.0     0.662799
21  0.0     0.463892
22  40000.0     1.881756
23  0.0     0.000000
24  145000.0    3.046823
25  12000.0     0.305522
26  0.0     2.475190
27  0.0     2.680435
28  0.0     0.343142
29  0.0     0.450021
30  0.0     -0.136755
```

I do not understand this. I expect column A to be scaled (and centered) too by the interquartile range (like in case of column B). What is the explanation here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your middle *50%* of values in `A` are all zero, thus the IQR as well as the overall median are both zero - effectively leading to no change when the median is removed as well as no change when the data is scaled according to the quantile range.

Comment: In this case this means that RobustScaler has the prerequisite of having some values in IQR, right? By the way, the denominator in RS is Q3-Q1 which is zero (uninterpretable) in case of my A, why doesn't it throw some kind of error instead of leaving all values unchanged?

Comment: `RobustScaler.fit()` calls `_handle_zeros_in_scale` on the IQR `scale_`, i.e. sets `scale_` to `1` if it is `0`, thus there is no error.